# Security risks monitoring JMX

Tags: ports, risk-analysis

I am doing an internship at a big company wich create industrial automated systems for some big company's. They want me to design a way to monitor all the Java based control modules. Now I am going to use JMX, but I have thought of a couple of ways of doing that, and they all include opening some ports. I was wondering what kind of security risks might come out of that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your threat model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An open port is an attack surface that can be exploited.  Reduce the number of open ports as much as possible. If a service isn't required to be accessed by the open internet,  then don't expose it.